# Retrieving an image file from parse.com and displaying in an image view

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I am trying to download the image from parse.com and display in a image view in an Activity extending AppCompatActivity.

I got this code from one of many searches:

```
ParseImageView mImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Appetizers"); // class name
    ParseFile postImage = object.getParseFile("imageFiles"); // column name
    String imageUrl = postImage.getUrl() ;//live url
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);

   Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(imageUri.toString()).into(mImage);
```

[image: My parse class]

File format: jpg

Comment: Sorry not an answer, but I faced the same question of yours some days ago (if I understood correctly) and solved easily with volley.

Comment: Sorry, what is volley?

Comment: Whats is the issue?

Comment: When i click on a row item, then an Activity will show up with the image in an image view, but all i get is an empty activity, no image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by debugging and setting logs everywhere ...

In the sending class:

```
ParseObject po = mAppetizers.get(position); // get position
String ID = po.getObjectId().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(Appetizer.this, AppetizerRecipe.class);

intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the receiver's class:

```
final ParseImageView mImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
String ID = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> getimage = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers");
    getimage.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
    getimage.whereEqualTo("ID", ID);
        Log.d("AppetizerRecipe2", "object: " + ID);
    getimage.getInBackground(ID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.v("what is e?", "e = " + e);
                // success
                final ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)object.get("imageFiles");
                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
                            // use data for something
                            Log.d("test", "Get your image..." + fileObject.getUrl());
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(fileObject.getUrl()).placeholder
                            (R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(mImage);

                        } else {
                            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // fail
                Log.d("test", "Error Message..." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. On my activity, extending AppCompatActivity, this is the code to download an image inside ImageView:

```
    ImageLoader.ImageCache imageCache = new BitmapLruCache();
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()), imageCache);
    NetworkImageView headshot = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.speaker_headshot);
    headshot.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
    headshot.setImageUrl("http://www.anydomain.com/anyimage.jpg", imageLoader);
```

As you see you will need an addicional class in your project, a file named **BitmapLruCache.java**. Here is the entire content of it:

```
public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {

public BitmapLruCache() { this(getDefaultLruCacheSize()); }

public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) { super(sizeInKiloBytes); }

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) { return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024; }

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) { return get(url); }

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) { put(url, bitmap); }

public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    return cacheSize;
}
}
```

Finally, for this to work you have to setup a special ImageView inside your layout **XML**:

```
            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/speaker_headshot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

**EDIT:** For all of this to work you have to import:

1) the Volley library. Do this on your Android Studio: menu File/Project Structure/Modules-app/Tab Dependencies. There you add (+ sign) a Library Dependency and find or search for **com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0**. That's it. **OR** simple include this in your build.gradle (module app) file:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

If you already have a "dependencies" section then just include the line inside it.

AND

2) Put a copy of **disklrucache-2.0.2.jar** into your "libs" folder ( get the .jar from here https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.jakewharton&a=disklrucache&v=LATEST ) OR insert another "compile" directive inside your "dependencies":

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
```

Comment: For any of this to work, do i need to install something?  Like ImageLoader, ImageCache or Volley?  Trying to find how to get these to work.

Comment: You just have to import Volley library. I've just edited my answer to clear things. To summarize: 1) import Volley library; 2) create a new file called BitmapLruCache.class with the provided content above; 3) edit your layout xml to put the special type of ImageView; 4) insert those five lines of code, provided at the beginning of my answer, inside your activity.

Comment: I added: compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0', i created a new java class called BitmapLruCache.java (right?) and added the contents, edited layout, insert the five lines of code inside activity. - the errors i am getting: 1) in the BitmapLruCache.java class, there is an error on the first @Override stating that the method does not override the method from its superclass 2) In the activity, the last two lines states if i have a file from drawable or url, i am trying to get the image from an image file in parse.  Very much appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: I am very sorry! Forgot something... now your will get it working. Import the necessary .jar or add compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'. See my edit, please. Thanks. Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: still getting the error with the override (method does not override or implement a method from a super type) and im not sure of the url for parse.  From what i read its .getUrl() but that isn't working

Comment: Now I think you just have to (menu) "Build/Clean Project" then "Build Rebuild Project. If this doesn't resolve, maybe you will have to (menu) "File/Invalidate Caches - Restart...".

Comment: Waw... please, certify that you have "import android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.util.LruCache; import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;" on top of your **BitmapLruCache.java** file, before "public class BitmapLruCache extends..."

Comment: Yes, i was missing 'import android.util.LruCache;' - it took away the override error, but still not able to see the image from parse.com.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114961/discussion-between-lizg-and-statosdotcom).

Answer (score 0):

try on this way.

```
ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Appetizers"); // class name

    ParseFile postImage = object.getParseFile("imageFiles"); // column name

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> getimage = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Appetizers"); // class
    getimage.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
                for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("imageFiles");

                    Log.d("test", "get your image ... " + fileObject.getUrl());
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(fileObject.getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .into(mImage);
                }
            } else {
                // fail
                Log.d("test", "error Message... " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

your have not set `picasso` place holder for clear catch memory form picasso lib.

Comment: this is working, only thing is that it is reading every image in the class and displaying the last one.  It is not displaying the one i clicked on.

Comment: any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: its store at parseFile Array list and last to display all image in adapter

Comment: I dont want a list to appear. I select an item in the list to show only 1 not all. What way can i do this?

Comment: From what code i have here now, it gives me the last item in the list. This is not what i am trying to do. I am trying to put whatever item i clicked on in an imageview